# How do I access to a variable inside a multiprocessing worker itself contained in a Qthread?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, qthread

I'm trying to access to a variable in a multiprocessing worker within a QThread.

I made a minimal example to highlight my point:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

class my_Thread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,M=100, N=100, nbCore=2):
        QThread.__init__(self, )
        self.M = M
        self.N = N
        self.nbCore = nbCore

    def run(self):
        self.my_worker = mp_worker_class()
        self.Mean = self.my_worker.start(self.nbCore, self.M, self.N)
        self.finished.emit()

    def returninfo(self):
        return self.my_worker.nbiter

class mp_worker_class():
    nbiter = 0
    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def start(self, nbCore=2, M=100, N=100 ):
        self.nbiter = 0
        X = np.random.rand(nbCore,M,N)
        pipe_list = []
        for i in range(nbCore):
            recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker, args=(X[i,:,:] , send_end))
            p.start()
            pipe_list.append(recv_end)

        for idx, recv_end in enumerate(pipe_list):
            Ymean =recv_end.recv()
            print(Ymean)

    @classmethod
    def mp_worker(self, X=None, send_end=None):
        mean = 0
        nb =0
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            for j in range(X.shape[1]):
                # print(self.nbiter)
                mean += X[i,j]
                nb += 1
                self.nbiter += 1
        mean /= nb
        send_end.send([mean])


class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.VBOX = QVBoxLayout()
        self.info_LE = QLineEdit()
        self.start_PB = QPushButton('Start')
        self.start_PB.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        self.VBOX.addWidget(self.info_LE)
        self.VBOX.addWidget(self.start_PB)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.VBOX)

    def startThread(self):
        self.thread = my_Thread(M=10000, N=10000, nbCore=5)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda msg=self.info_LE, x=self.thread: self.updatemsgs(msg, x))
        self.timer.start()
        self.ElapsedTimer = QElapsedTimer()
        self.ElapsedTimer.start()

        self.thread.start()

    def threadFinished(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.thread.exit()
        print('Finished')

    def updatemsgs(self, msg, Obj):
        nbiter = Obj.returninfo()
        print(nbiter)
        msg.setText(str(nbiter))
        self.parent.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In this example, I created the class `my_Thread` which inherits from `Qthread`. In this `QThread` class I call a multiprocessing worker through the class `mp_worker_class` which calls 5 times the function `mp_worker` in parallel. In the class `mp_worker_class` I have a variable `nbiter = 0` which is increased by one each time I do a loop in the function `mp_worker`. I can verify `nbiter`is indeed increasing because I can see its value through a print. But from the `my_Thread.returninfo()` function from where I just return the `nbiter`value from the `mp_worker_class` class, I just get zero.

What I would like is print the value of `mp_worker_class.nbiter` in the pyqt5 QlineEdit wighet (info_LE) that I can see in the GUI. I update the text every 0.1 second. For now it just prints zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child processes in Python do not share memory by default—code running in one process cannot access or change the memory used by another process. This means that each process has its own copy of each of the variables you are using, including the `mp_worker_class.nbiter` variable. Hence, you don't see changes that a child process makes to its `mp_worker_class.nbiter` variable from the parent process (or any of the other child processes, for that matter.)

As you have seen, we can get data from a parent process to a child process by using the `args` keyword argument to the `multiprocessing.Process` constructor. However, this simply copies the data from the parent to the child; we're still not sharing memory between the two processes.

```py
import multiprocessing

def my_example(arg):
    arg.append(35)
    print("Child arg:",arg)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [1,2,3]
    print("Before:",l)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_example, args=(l,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print("After:",l)
    
# Before: [1, 2, 3]
# Child arg: [1, 2, 3, 35]
# After: [1, 2, 3]
```

Fortunately, `multiprocessing` provides a [Value class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) which makes it easy to  create a variable in shared memory. The key is to create the `Value` in the parent process and then distribute the `Value` to the child processes through the `args` parameter to `multiprocessing.Process`.

---

In your code, you could create your `multiprocessing.Value` in the constructor for `my_Thread`. For example, you could add

```py
self.nbiter = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
```

This creates an integer `multiprocessing.Value` (that is what `i` means) and initializes it to 0. You could then pass this `Value` to the `self.my_worker.start` classmethod, which could, in turn, pass the `Value` to its child `mp_worker` processes.

The raw value associated with a `multiprocessing.Value` object can be accessed via its `value` attribute. Hence, you would need to change the code in your `mp_worker` classmethod to change the `value` attribute of your `multiprocessing.Value` object.

You would also need to account for the fact that the `+=` operation will not be atomic when using `multiprocessing.Value`. Hence, your code needs to acquire a lock on the `Value` before incrementing. If created a new argument to `mp_worker` called `nbiter`, your code for incrementing `nbiter` should look like this.

```py
with nbiter.get_lock():
    nbiter.value += 1
```

You will also need to change your `my_Thread.returninfo` method to simply return `self.nbiter.value`. You may also want to set `self.nbiter.value = 0` at the beginning of your `my_Thread.run` method if `my_Thread` will be restarted for some reason.

In summary, your code could look something like this.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

class my_Thread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,M=100, N=100, nbCore=2):
        QThread.__init__(self, )
        self.M = M
        self.N = N
        self.nbCore = nbCore
        self.nbiter = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)

    def run(self):
        self.nbiter.value = 0
        self.my_worker = mp_worker_class()
        self.Mean = self.my_worker.start(self.nbCore, self.M, self.N, self.nbiter)
        self.finished.emit()

    def returninfo(self):
        return self.nbiter.value

class mp_worker_class():
    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def start(self, nbCore=2, M=100, N=100, nbiter=None ):
        X = np.random.rand(nbCore,M,N)
        pipe_list = []
        for i in range(nbCore):
            recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker, args=(X[i,:,:] , send_end, nbiter))
            p.start()
            pipe_list.append(recv_end)

        for idx, recv_end in enumerate(pipe_list):
            Ymean =recv_end.recv()
            print(Ymean)

    @classmethod
    def mp_worker(self, X=None, send_end=None, nbiter=None):
        mean = 0
        nb =0
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            for j in range(X.shape[1]):
                # print(self.nbiter)
                mean += X[i,j]
                nb += 1
                with nbiter.get_lock():
                    nbiter.value += 1
        mean /= nb
        send_end.send([mean])


class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.VBOX = QVBoxLayout()
        self.info_LE = QLineEdit()
        self.start_PB = QPushButton('Start')
        self.start_PB.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        self.VBOX.addWidget(self.info_LE)
        self.VBOX.addWidget(self.start_PB)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.VBOX)

    def startThread(self):
        self.thread = my_Thread(M=10000, N=10000, nbCore=5)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda msg=self.info_LE, x=self.thread: self.updatemsgs(msg, x))
        self.timer.start()
        self.ElapsedTimer = QElapsedTimer()
        self.ElapsedTimer.start()

        self.thread.start()

    def threadFinished(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.thread.exit()
        print('Finished')

    def updatemsgs(self, msg, Obj):
        nbiter = Obj.returninfo()
        print(nbiter)
        msg.setText(str(nbiter))
        self.parent.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```